# Webpack Babel-loader - not supported in a preset

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

I have been trying to solve the following error for the past 2 days but to no avail: 
[image]

I tried playing around with the .babelrc file and subsequently decided to include the presets in the webpack config file itself. 
The following is my babel-loader configuration in webpack.config.js.

```
rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            babelrc: false,
            cacheDirectory: true,
            presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"]
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
        }
      ],
    }
  ]
```

The following is my package.json info:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-alpha.9",
    "babel-loader": "7.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "7.0.0-alpha.9",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "6.24.1",
    "webpack": "2.4.1",
    "webpack-chunk-hash": "0.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.10.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.14.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.0",
   }
```

If any light could be shed on what's causing this error, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest testing it with a stable version of Babel (7 is alpha, as can plainly be seen in your package.json)

Comment: It is because you're using the 7.x version of Babel's core, and 6.x version of your presets. The 6.x preset for React is doing stuff that isn't allowed in 7.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`babel-core`'s `7.x` version has stricter restrictions on what presets can do. Since you're still using `babel-preset-react@6.24.1`, it will fail.

If you're going to use the `7.0.0-alpha.X` releases, you should do it for all the presets and `babel-register` too.